# python json.loads(req.stream.read().decode("utf-8")) fails on on_post

Tags: python, python-2.7, falconframework

I have a web service written in Python 2.7 that uses the Falcon framework. One particular method accepts a post of json values. My code:

```
 def on_post(self, req, resp):
    response = dict()
    try:
        data = simplejson.load(req.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))
        logger.info(data)
        mapUrl = data['url']
        #mapUrl = req.get_params("url", None)
        response['url'] = add_google_key(mapUrl)
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.body = simplejson.dumps(response)
    except Exception, ex:
        response['error'] = "Error occured"
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_400
        resp.body = simplejson.dumps(response)
        return resp
```

I'm working on pycharm IDE, and it just timeout while executing
`simplejson.load(req.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))`

Other things I've tried all failing to read json
`json.loads(req.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))`

The curl request I'm trying:

```
POST /add HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
"url": "www.google.com"
}
```

Environment: OSX Sierra Python 2.7 Falcon 0.3.0 and other is the latest version from Pip

Comment: Is an exception caught, and if yes, what kind (full stacktrace)?

Comment: there is no exception caught, it just hangs up and gets time out later on

Comment: Rewrite nested/chained methods and log it step-by-step, i.e.:
1) content = req.stream.read()  2) log content; 3) decode, log ...
And show results

Comment: I suggest you provide more debug log and execution logs so it will easy to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal conditions, req.stream is an instance of `<class gunicorn.http.body.Body>`. However, during testing it is a `<class wsgiref.validate.InputWrapper>`. Both have read() methods, but they differ as such:

`gunicorn.http.body.Body`:

```
def read(self, size=None):
size = self.getsize(size)
if size == 0:
    return b""
# ...snip...
```

`wsgiref.validate.InputWrapper`:

```
def read(self, *args):
assert_(len(args) == 1)
v = self.input.read(*args)
assert_(type(v) is bytes)
return v
```

**InputWrapper** throws an AssertionError because the call to `req.stream.read()` in my middleware doesn't declare a value for size! Normally it's not needed because gunicorn sets the size automatically, but **InputWrapper** only asserts that it needs to be set.

### Solution

```
# previous code
data = simplejson.load(req.stream.read(req.content_length or 0))
# remaining code
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other recently posted answer, [`req.stream`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response_wsgi.html#falcon.Request.stream) is, indeed, the raw stream directly from the application server. Falcon provides the same workaround as [`req.bounded_stream`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response_wsgi.html#falcon.Request.bounded_stream); see also: [Why does req.stream.read() hang for certain requests?](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/faq.html#why-does-req-stream-read-hang-for-certain-requests)

Reading data from `req.bounded_stream`:

```py
def on_post(self, req, resp):
    data = simplejson.loads(req.bounded_stream.read().decode())
    logger.info(data)
    # ...
```

The following is also safe:

```py
def on_post(self, req, resp):
    data = json.load(req.bounded_stream)
    logger.info(data)
    # ...
```

However, for standard Internet media types like JSON, you could also check out Falcon's built-in [media handling](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/media.html), which provides the same functionality with even less boilerplate:

```py
def on_post(self, req, resp):
    data = req.get_media()
    logger.info(data)
    # ...

    # You can also set response JSON by simply assigning to resp.media
    resp.media = {'message': 'Hello from Stack Overflow!'}
```